# Problems setting gui wallet on Tails

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I get these two situations...

**If I try to run the wallet gui file with that command, it shows as following:**

amnesia@amnesia:~/Persistent/Tor Browser/monero-wallet-gui$ ./monero-wallet-gui ./monero-wallet-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Quick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Also if I try to run from the script provided, I get the following:**

./start-gui.sh 
./monero-wallet-gui: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./monero-wallet-gui)
./monero-wallet-gui: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/amnesia/Persistent/Tor Browser/monero-wallet-gui/libs/libproxy.so.1)

How to correct these? Thanks in advance (:

Extra: I do have the correct (32 bit) installed and also the latest Tails build.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the applicable libraries for the build.

If you go to the Monero github page.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero

and scroll down to: Compiling Monero from Source.

And install the necessary libraries highlighted, that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe 64-bit is still a requirement for the GUI client.

Also, TAILS intentionally makes it difficult to install new packages and libraries.

I recently attempted running a miner client which TAILS told me had missing dependencies. Subsequently, I attempted to install the dependencies in the terminal with `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`, but it produced an error I'd never seen before, something like 'UNIX 13 error ...'.

You might try and see if you are able to install the needed dependencies using a similar command in your terminal in TAILS, something like: `sudo apt-get install GLIBCXX_3.4.21`.

I would think that the ability to package applications in a portable fashion would improve over time going forward as a result of the 'containerization' trend (*a la* Docker)...

Hope this helps explain what's (most likely) happening for you at least.

Have you tried the CLI (command-line) Wallet on TAILS yet?

Comment: Also: You can consider trying to download any needed dependencies from another system onto a USB, loading them up while in TAILS, and moving them to the specified locations in the Live OS.

Comment: You will need to make sure you had set an Administrator password during initial pre-boot process. Click on the '+' button to see these options: Additional Settings dialog appears, click on Administration Password. Specify a password of your choice in both the Administration Password and Confirm text boxes then click Add. see: [tails tutorial on setting admin password](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/administration_password/index.en.html)